# Multiple versions of library with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have the problem that Gradle is pulling in two versions of a library, which is causing runtime issues. These versions are both necessary, and are dependencies of two of the dependencies I have. Library A needs Library C version x, and Library B needs Library C version y. At runtime, the incorrect version of Library C is used, causing a NoSuchFieldError. Is this something I can resolve in Gradle? Or is it more of an issue for my IDE/JVM options?

Comment: This is a limitation of Java; if you end up with two versions of a library on the classpath, there is no good way to distinguish them, leading to all sorts of weird runtime errors.

Comment: That is a real bummer. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

In general Gradle will do the right thing by choosing the latest version of a library when there are dependency conflicts. However for various reasons this may not always work correctly. To get around this you can tell Gradle explicitly to **not** include a certain transitive dependency during its resolution. Here is an example:

```
compile (group:'com.project', name:'library', version:'1.0')  {
    // These lines will exclude these other libraries from being included
    exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    exclude module: 'log4j'
    exclude module: 'commons-lang'
}
```

You can make this more fine grained if you need to, but I've found excluding modules seems to work well for me.